# Is it good idea to put a slide about "National Teacher Appreciation Day" at the end of presentation slides at my masters defense?

Tags: thesis, defense, presentation

Tomorrow I have my master's project defense. So, I will be presenting and defending on my project "Course Advising System".

I just noticed that tomorrow is a National Teacher Appreciation Day. Is it a good idea to put one slide after "Questions and Comments" section in the presentation?

I want to put this slide but I don't want to ruin anything either.

[image]

Comment: Among other factors, this will depend on whether anyone in the audience considers themselves to be linked to the profession of a "teacher" (which may be seen differently by culture) in any way.

Comment: I would like to tell you that the date on which [Teachers' Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teachers%27_Day) is celebrated varies from country to country. This slide may work in your location, but it's meaningless to many others.

Comment: @scaaahu So what? Do you think it's likely that the asker will present in multiple different countries on the given day?

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that you showing or not showing the slide will make much of a difference one way or the other, but as a general rule, if I were one of the professors at your defense, I would not expect or want you to say or display anything that makes it seem like you are trying to ingratiate yourself with me in any way other than by performing well and conducting yourself professionally. I don't need to be thanked profusely, and don't need to be "appreciated" in any special way for doing my job.

Moreover, if you think about it, the reason something like National Teacher Appreciation Day was conceived is probably because in many countries being a schoolteacher is a very ungrateful, poorly appreciated job. For example in the U.S., teachers get paid very little, are commensurately not respected by much of society, and sometimes are outright hated by certain people for purely political reasons. All of this does not apply to university professors, who are generally treated quite well and held in pretty high regard by most people, and consequently aren't in great need for a "professor appreciation day".

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your locale

> It is fine

Although I doubt it will make any impact on your defence *per se*, it might give a positive outlook. There doesn't seem to be anything negative about it.